# Yahoo's Mojito Manhattan cocktail mix, when/where can I use it?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, css, yahoo

Early this month Yahoo! announced Mojito framework. They will open source it in 2012.

I'm looking for more information about this fantastic framework with no luck.

Where can I find it? Do I need to wait until it will be open sourced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to wait till it will be open source. Type Yahoo Mojito release on Google and you will see that [link](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/11/cocktails-with-mojito-manhattan) that says this:

> Yahoo! plans to open source Mojito through the Yahoo Developer Network
>   in the first quarter of 2012. Manhattan will be available later in
>   2012. To take a quick peek of Cocktails, watch the Yahoo! Mojito and Yahoo! Manhattan Demo. There's not a lot of information for developers
>   at this time, but the blog post titled "Yahoo reveals their Node.js
>   Mojito Manhattan cocktail mix - now I can talk about it?" by David
>   Herron, author of Node Web Development, gives us a little information
>   of how things worked before he left the Cocktails team in June.

Comment: the link to David Herron's blog - http://nodejs.davidherron.com/2011/11/yahoo-reveals-their-nodejs-mojito.html

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo just released Mojito this morning.
It is available on github here: https://github.com/yahoo/mojito
Documentation also available here: http://developer.yahoo.com/cocktails/mojito/docs/